# Specify the return type as a parameter for a function with generics

Tags: java, spring, generics, parameters, jackson

I am struggling with generic parameters with function scope. Following is my function.

```
public <RES, REQ> RES makePostRequest(String postRequest, REQ requestBody, Class<RES> type) {
        Response<type> resp = restTemplate.postForObject(postRequest, requestBody, Response.class);
        return resp.getBody();
}
```

Jackson , the json library that does the deserialization needs the return type to be specified. Otherwise the response is not converted to the correct type. However, `Response<type>` is invalid. How does one take the `RES` as a parameter and specify it within `Response<RES>`?

Note: I do not want to use `restTemplate.exchange`. I do not want to set all the http headers and create an http entity. I just want to specify the generic type through a parameter. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return restTemplate.postForObject(postRequest, requestBody, type);
```

or else:

```
ResponseEntity<RES> resp = restTemplate.postForEntity(postRequest, requestBody, type);
return resp.getBody();
```